# Unable to get value of a variable from another Play in Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

I wish to obtain the value of "fdet_APP" variable of Play 2 into Play 3.

Below is my playbook which case be used as a testcase:

```
- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - add_host: name={{ item }}
                        groups=dest_nodes
                        ansible_user={{ USER }}
     with_items: "{{ Dest_IP.split(',') }}"

- name: "Play 2"
  hosts: dest_nodes
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  tasks:
   - set_fact:
       fdet_APP: "Yellow"

- name: "Play 3"
  hosts: localhost
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  vars:
    dbfiledet: "{{ hostvars['dest_nodes']['fdet_APP'] }}"

  tasks:
   - debug: msg="{{ dbfiledet.stdout }}"
```

I get the below error for my attempt:

playbook RUN command:

```
ansible-playbook variabletest.yml -e "USER=user1 Dest_IP=10.17.44.26,10.17.54.26"
```

> [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
>
> PLAY [Play 1]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [add_host]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************* changed: [localhost] => (item=10.17.44.26) changed: [localhost] =>
>   (item=10.17.54.26)
>
> PLAY [Play 2]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [10.17.54.26] ok: [10.17.44.26]
>
> TASK [set_fact]
>   ********************************************************************************************************************************************* ok: [10.17.44.26] ok: [10.17.54.26]
>
> PLAY [Play 3]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************** ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [debug]
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************ fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
>   with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['dest_nodes']\"
>   is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in 'variabletest.yml': line
>   36, column 6, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n   - debug:
>   msg=\"{{ dbfiledet.stdout }}\"\n     ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but
>   this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always
>   quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For
>   instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written
>   as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> 10.17.44.26                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
>   10.17.54.26                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0    localhost
>   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0
>   rescued=0    ignored=0

I'm on the latest version of ansible and python 2.7.5

Can someone suggest what is wrong and how can i get the value for the variable in Play 3 please ?

Answer (score 0):

`hostvars` are tied to a single Ansible managed host, not an inventory group. Try running `debug: var=hostvars` to see what I mean. In your case `dest_nodes` is an inventory group, not a host.

If just want to pull the variable from any host in the group, try:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[groups.dest_nodes|first]['fdet_APP'] }}"
```

If you are looking to parse the value for all hosts in the group, then you'll need to implement either a loop or a `json_query` filter